# Finding code in MFC32 binary

Tags: disassembly, windows, serial-communication, mfc

I am trying to figure out where the code is that interacts with the Serial Port on an MFC Win32 binary - and am utterly out of ideas on how to find this code block.

I have even tried, say, stopping the process right before I click the button to initialize serial communication and then stepping through. The program returns with an error immediately.

I have even tried setting a breakpoint over the string text of the error message in the `.data` segment, and even then no breakpoint.

What is causing this? Why can't I just step through a process to see where its contacting the serial port?

How is it possible that its hiding at this level?

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal to do the job? Also, depending on the program it could use/require a specific driver through which it talks to the serial port or it could use simply `CreateFile` or its native counterpart `NtCreateFile`. But in general when communication with a driver is involved you can expect there to be a call to something like `CreateFile`. Windows is not so dissimilar to Unix, since the object manager namespace also has just a single root and you talk to devices the same way as you read/write files.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the tool API Monitor. It took a ton of filtering, but I eventually found a reference to CreateFileA. Odd, because Ida Pro does not reference CreateFileA anywhere. Either way, it works! Thank you!

Comment: Is it a statically or dynamically linked executable?  If dynamic, the call to CreateFileA will be probably be in one of the MFC dlls, not in the executable itself.

Comment: MFC apps are more likely to use something like `CFile` or `CArchive` class for I/O than direct API calls.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to attach to the desired process with ollydbg or something similar and breakpoint [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),[WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (If you also need the information about the connection itself like baudrate or stuff like that you will have to set a breakpoint at [SetCommState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa363436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) too.)

After hitting a breakpoint you just have to follow the pointer on top of the stack to get to the position the current function got called.